# dump/restore table into/from chunks

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a very large database of millions of rows. I want to dump the table into chunks by using the registration that can start from 0 to 9 or from a to z; So I have run this scrypt which return me plain text for each registration:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E G H I K L M N O P R S T W Y Z;
do
echo "exporting registration beginning with $i"
    psql "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=user password=password" -c "\copy (
        SELECT * from registration_table_2021_06 where left(registration_no, 1) = '$i') TO '/path/to/folder/where/are/the/chunks_$i"
done
```

What I would like to know if first of all the process is correct as it is, if not how can split a huge table into chunks with just the data.

If the process is correct how I recompile all the chunks again into a new table in other database.

Comment: "millions of rows" is not really a very large database. (Hundreds of millions might be). What is the actual, underlying problem are you trying to achieve by splitting the dump?

Comment: BTW `for i in {1..9} {A..Z}` and `... registration_no like '$i%'`

Comment: If `registration_table_2021_06` is an active table the above is not going to yield a coherent snashot of the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The table is static, data doesn't grow, main issue is that when uploading from local to production instance it takes days to upload the whole table, having issues with the server so I thought splitting the table into chunks to later merge them in the server would make smooth the work. It is a process we will need to do once a month as the data is released once a month.

Comment: Create a single, large dump. Split the dump file. Upload the parts to the server, join the parts together, then restore the dump on the server.

Comment: Any triggers/indexes on the table? Because "days" = "terabytes" of data.

Comment: @Abelisto yes two indexes in registration_no and geom not triggers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I read about the split command but I thought it just work for whole database https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html

Comment: Hope you droped those indexes before load the data?

Comment: Yes I created them later of uploading the data into local. But know I will remind to delete when the new dataset was released thanks

Comment: Also don't forget to drop PK/unique constraints if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that covers all data (for example, no NULL values), that should be OK. But since this requires many sequential scans of the large table, it will probably not perform well.

I don't know what advantage you see in splitting up the dump that way, but table partitioning would do the job nicely. If only you had thought of that *before* the table grew large!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is I am working on local manging this huge datasets but when we need on production upload the table takes days and the server close abruptly so it is not very sure to do it like that. SO I thought in split the table into chunks to later merge them within the server. The table doesn't grow it is a table which is large itself and is updated once a month so it needs to be analysed in local and deployed to production once a month.